# Yolo implementation in ordinary Python script

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I would like to implement YOLO from scratch. I have seen codes available in github but I want to try from scratch. Is it possible to implement YOLO in ordinary Python script without using dark flow? I am planning to implement it in keras.

Comment: Here's the original paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640

Answer (score 1):

All Kinds of neural networks can be implemented on python from scratch. If you really want to do so you can. You can use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) library and [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) libraries for the easy calculations with vectors and matrices.

Comment: keras is built on tensorflow know, he wants to build it from scratch

Comment: You can always use Numpy if you want to implement both forward and backward propogation and Tensorflow if you only want to implement forward propagation. Oh, my bad @S.Ruka

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to do is a time-consuming task. Will not be easy. But if you try hard, you could do it. And don't forget to share the code with us.

First, you will need to get a basic understanding of the `YOLO` network. I would suggest reading the research papers.
 Original `YOLO` paper and the second paper discuss many details about the network and how it works. It will give you a better understanding of the network and how it is working and will be helpful when debugging your own network.

The third paper is easier than the other two. It will only explain the modifications that they have done. So, in order to get a full understanding of the network, you still have to read all three research papers.

1. [Original Yolo Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640)
2. [Yolo9000 (Yolo version 2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08242)
3. [Yolov3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02767)

After you have downloaded the `YOLO`, you will find a file called `yolo.cfg`. You can open that file in a notepad.

At the top of the file, they have defined some hyperparameters. You can know the meaning of those parameters by reading the papers. 
After that, they have described their `YOLO` network as `caffe` people do in their `prototxt` files. It is not exactly as same as the `prototxt` file, but you can get the idea. It would be very helpful when building your own network.

They have written the `YOLO` network in such a way that the network changes a lot when it changes the mode from training to testing. You can find all that information in their research papers. Keep that in your mind too.

Happy Coding !!!